# Angular -Js $http.post not working in django

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, django

I have just started Django and what I was trying to implement $http.post method of angular to post form data to my Django database,and my further plan was to update the view to display the results without page refresh.so what i thought to post data in django db and then my view function will return a jsonresponse,of that posted data which i can use to update the view using $http.get method.

But the problem is occuring with me is whenever i post data it is not able to post the data and returning an empty json response.

Here is my codes which i am working on:-

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
app_name='demo'
urlpatterns=[
    url(r'^$',views.index,name="index"),
    url(r'^add_card/$',views.add_card,name="add_card")

]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse,JsonResponse
from .forms import CardForm
from .models import Card
# Create your views here.

def add_card(request):
    saved = False
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #print('hi')
        form = CardForm(request.POST)
        #print('hi')
        if form.is_valid():
            #print('hi')
            card = Card()
            #print('hi')
            card.content = form.cleaned_data['content']
            #print('hi')
            saved = True
            card.save()
            #print('hi')
        return JsonResponse({'body':list(q.content for q in Card.objects.order_by('-id')[:15])})

    else:
        return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps({"nothing to see": "this isn't happening"}),
            content_type="application/json"
        )

def index(request):
    return render(request,'demo/index.html',{'form':CardForm()})
```

**controller.js**

```
var nameSpace = angular.module("ajax", ['ngCookies']);

nameSpace.controller("MyFormCtrl", ['$scope', '$http', '$cookies',
function ($scope, $http, $cookies) {
    $http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
    // To send the csrf code.
    $http.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRFToken'] = $cookies.get('csrftoken');

    // This function is called when the form is submitted.
    $scope.submit = function ($event) {
        // Prevent page reload.
        $event.preventDefault();
        // Send the data.
        var in_data = jQuery.param({'content': $scope.card.content,'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $cookies.csrftoken});
        $http.post('add_card/', in_data)
          .then(function(json) {
            // Reset the form in case of success.
            console.log(json.data);
            $scope.card = angular.copy({});
        });
    }
 }]);
```

My models.py:-

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Card(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.content
```

My forms.py-

```
from django import forms
from .models import Card

class CardForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Card
        fields = ['content']
```

Comment: You are returning a JsonResponse with {'body': ... } but in you Angular code you are logging json.data. Try replacing **body** with **data** to see if you get any response.

Comment: If i change data with body the console is printing undefined... actually the json which i get on success response is like this `Object {data: Object, status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK", headers: function}`,in which body resides in data part that's why i logged json.data there @dentemm

Comment: Okay, and if you log json.data.body?

Comment: Ok that's fine But my main problem is that my view.py code is not able to post the data in my database,so my first purpose is to get that data saved then i will think about the json @dentemm,Can You please suggest me some edits in my view.py file that will be a great help thanks.

Comment: Okay I didn't understand, I will try to create an answer

Comment: Are you able to go inside your add_card view function's POST?

Comment: No after `if form.is_valid` my code is not implementing i dont why @PansulBhatt

Comment: So does it enter the if condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some problems in your `view.py` code.

1. You need to create a new object in your database from the request data
2. You need to return the new data as a response

   ```
   if form.is_valid():
       new_content = form.cleaned_data['content']
       card = Card.objects.create(content=new_content)
       return JsonResponse(
              list(Card.objects.all().order_by('-id').values('content')[:15]),
              safe=False
       )
   ```

   That should return a list of the `content` value of your first 15 objects in your `Card` table after creating a new object in that table by the content provided, IF your form is valid.
3. Also your `CardForm` should be defined as follows:

   ```
   class CardForm(forms.ModelForm):
       class Meta:
           model = Card
           fields = ('content',)
   ```
4. Finally, your `$http.post` call is asynchronous, which means that when the `.then` is reached, there is a probability (almost a certainty) that the post request has not been resolved yet, thus your `json.data` is empty. To solve this problem:

   ```
   $http.post('add_card/', in_data)
       .then((json) => {
           // Reset the form in case of success.
           console.log(json.data);
           $scope.card = angular.copy({});
   });
   ```

   A far better read and solutions on the asynchronous-to-synchronous calls are: [ES6 Promises - Calling synchronous functions within promise chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34348285/es6-promises-calling-synchronous-functions-within-promise-chain), [How do you synchronously resolve a chain of es6 promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28683071/how-do-you-synchronously-resolve-a-chain-of-es6-promises?answertab=votes#tab-top) and [Synchronous or Sequential fetch in Service Worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32460156/synchronous-or-sequential-fetch-in-service-worker)

Good luck :)

Comment: Sir, I applied the changes but it is still returning an empty json and the the posted data are not being saved @john Moutafis

Comment: Can you provide your `Card` model from the `models.py` in your question as an edit?

Comment: I have edited the JsonResponse, and a possible problem in your form, have a look

Comment: it is giving `syntax error for safe=False` @john Moutafis and also if i remove it it gives another Typeerror of unhashable list

Comment: My fault, I forgot the {} from the previous edit, I reedited the answer

Comment: Now it is returning an empty array i don't know why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141989/discussion-between-vinit-raj-and-john-moutafis).

Comment: Sorry I was away of my computer for a bit there, I have edited my answer further to (hopefully) suite your needs!